# Use ternary operator inside object to define it's property

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to decide which property in object is going to be defined depending on condition? For example:

```
props="{
   'prop1': {label: 'Prop1'},
   hasProp2 ? '(prop2': {label: 'Prop2'}) : ('prop3': {label: 'Prop3'}),
   'prop4': {label: 'Prop4'}
}"
```

And let's say `hasProp2` is `computed property` with a function which returns `true` or `false`. How can I use `ternary operator` or basic `if statement` inside object or is it even possible?

Comment: Why is this tagged as PHP?

Comment: @WillardSolutions removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test it realy simple

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

var c = {
    prop_a: a = 1 ? 'YES' : 'NO'
}

console.log(c);
```

As you can see it it possible. Vue is reactive, and will work too.